# Unzip *.docx file in memory without write to disk - Java

Tags: java, zip, extract, unzip, in-memory

I want to unzip *.docx file in memory without to write the output to the disk. I found the following implementation but it allows only to read the compressed files but not to see the directory structure. It is important for me to know the location of each file in the directory tree. can somebody give me a direction?

```
private static void UnzipFileInMemory() {
    try {
        ZipFile zf = new ZipFile("d:\\a.docx");

        int i = 0;
        for (Enumeration e = zf.entries(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
            InputStream in = null;
            try {
                ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) e.nextElement();
                System.out.println(entry);
                in = zf.getInputStream(entry);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                //Logger.getLogger(Tester.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } finally {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    //Logger.getLogger(Tester.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }

        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        //Logger.getLogger(Tester.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ZipInputStream : zEntry in this example gives you file location.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

public class unzip {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String filePath = "D:/Tmp/Tmp.zip";
        String oPath = "D:/Tmp/";

        new unzip().unzipFile(filePath, oPath);
    }

    public void unzipFile(String filePath, String oPath) {

        FileInputStream fis = null;
        ZipInputStream zipIs = null;
        ZipEntry zEntry = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            zipIs = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(fis));
            while ((zEntry = zipIs.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                try {                   
                    FileOutputStream fos = null;
                    String opFilePath = oPath + zEntry.getName();
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(opFilePath);
                    System.out.println(zEntry.getName());

                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();
                } catch (Exception ex) {

                }
            }
            zipIs.close();
            fis.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You associate the zip format file as a virtual file system (FileSystem). For that java already has a protocol handler, for `jar:file://...`. So you have to prepend a `File.toURI()` with `"jar:"`.

```
URI docxUri = ,,, // "jar:file:/C:/... .docx"
Map<String, String> zipProperties = new HashMap<>();
zipProperties.put("encoding", "UTF-8");
try (FileSystem zipFS = FileSystems.newFileSystem(docxUri, zipProperties)) {
    Path documentXmlPath = zipFS.getPath("/word/document.xml");
```

Now you may use `Files.delete()` or `Files.copy` between real disk filesystem and zip.

When using XML:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

Document doc = builder.parse(Files.newInputStream(documentXmlPath));
//Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
```

You can then use XPath to find the places, and write the XML back again.

It even might be that you do not need XML but could replace place holders:

```
byte[] content = Files.readAllBytes(documentXmlPath);
String xml = new String(content, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
xml = xml.replace("#DATE#", "2014-09-24");
xml = xml.replace("#NAME#", StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml("Sniper")));
...
content = xml.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
Files.delete(documentXmlPath);
Files.write(documentXmlPath, content);
```

For a fast development, rename a copy of the .docx to a name with the .zip file extension, and inspect the files.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a file checking code within your loop:

```
if (!entry.isDirectory()) // Alternatively: if(entry.getName().contains("."))
    System.out.println(entry);
```